# Updating NSTableView datasource asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have been googling on this subject, but didn't seem able to find a consensus on the solution to this type of problem. When I use a data source with an NSTableView, if I need to populate the data source in background, there're a couple questions that pop in my mind regarding threading. I'm hoping to get some guidance here.

1. What would happen if I modified the data source between the main threading calling [NSTableView numberOfRowsInTableView:] and [NStableView tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:]? If the object the table view is asking for isn't valid anymore, what should I do?
2. Is making change to data source only on main thread the solution to this situation?
3. If 2 is the answer, does it apply to the case when binding is used?

Answer (score 1):

If your data source takes some time to populate, and you're currently showing a table with older data, I think you have a couple of options:

- Show a spinner over the UI while the re-population occurs, then call [tableView reloadData]
- Keep the older data around so the tableView remains responsive, then once the new data has been fetched/computed, tell the datasource about the new NSArray (or whatever object holds the new data), and call [tableView reloadData].

You can't be changing the data backing your datasource on the fly, unless you inform the tableView of each item/row changing as you go.

To address the threading part, you can use a background thread to populate an NSArray of new data, once complete switch to the main thread, and on that call [dataSource setBackingArray:newStuff];  [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Graham, conceptually I understand what you are saying. But seems to me, what happens between I modify data source and call [tableView reloadData] is the key. For example: 1)main thread calls [NSTableView numberOfRowsInTableView:], 2) I clear up data source on another thread, 3) main thread calls [NStableView tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:] with an index that isn't valid anymore. 4) call [tableView reloadData].

Comment: Right, so avoid that problem. Your datasource might have two arrays, currentData and incomingData. Always use currentData when responding to the table view. Once incomingData is complete, assign that to currentData and tell the table to reload. There's no "in-between" the assignment and the call to reload, so the table view stays consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Graham Perks in comments to one of answers. This actually an answer worth to be written out explicitly. I want just to add small snippet from my project as illustration:

```
- (void) populateTable
{
    DAL *dal = [[DAL alloc] init];  // MySQL engine
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *records = [dal RetrieveRecordswithSql:@"select id, serial, scannerid, scans, offloaded, uploaded from scan_set_v3" withColumnsCount:@(6) andColumnsDelimiter:ScanSetRecordColumnDelimiter];
    for (NSString *rec in records) {
        ScanSetRecord *newRec = [[ScanSetRecord alloc] initWithScanSet:rec];
        if (newRec) {
            [tmp addObject:newRec];
        }
    }
    self.dataArray = tmp;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```